# There's a way to get a callback after change image info in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to get a callback after change the ALT attribute in the image. The image above show the funcionality.

1. After include the image, I clicked on the image and then clicked on the Image Options button (or Insert/Edit Image).
2. Will open an window. After change the data, I want a callback, to get the new alternative text and then save in the database.

I tried [these options](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/), but doesn't work.

My TinyMCE plugin is the [TinyMCE Rails Gem](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails). The tinymce works fine, I only want a callback to get the alt attr after change using the TinyMCE's default dialog.

TinyMCE settings:

```
  tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea.tinymce",
    menubar: false,
    paste_as_text: true,
    resize: true,
    height: 500,
    language: "pt_BR",
    style_formats: [{"title":"Título Principal","block":"h1"},{"title":"Título Secundário","block":"h2"},{"title":"Título Terciário","block":"h3"},{"title":"Título Menor","block":"h4"},{"title":"Parágrafo normal","block":"p"}],
    plugins: "link,autolink,advlist,paste,lists,textcolor,colorpicker,hr,emoticons,imagetools,wordcount",
    toolbar: ["undo redo removeformat | styleselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent hr | link | forecolor backcolor emoticons"]
  });
```

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

After changing the tinymce settings, including the `file_browser_callback`, nothing happens. The code is:

TinyMCE settings:

```
  tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea.tinymce",
    menubar: false,
    paste_as_text: true,
    resize: true,
    height: 500,
    language: "pt_BR",
    style_formats: [{"title":"Título Principal","block":"h1"},{"title":"Título Secundário","block":"h2"},{"title":"Título Terciário","block":"h3"},{"title":"Título Menor","block":"h4"},{"title":"Parágrafo normal","block":"p"}],
    plugins: "link,autolink,advlist,paste,lists,textcolor,colorpicker,hr,emoticons,imagetools,wordcount",
    toolbar: ["undo redo removeformat | styleselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent hr | link | forecolor backcolor emoticons"],
    file_browser_callback: "UpdateImgAlt"
  });
```

function to get the callback:

```
function UpdateImgAlt(callback, value, meta){
  console.log('callback: '+callback);
  console.log('value: '+value);
  console.log('meta: '+meta);
}
```

Comment: what an error when you try `file_browser_callback` ?

Comment: @rails-id Hello! When I use the `file_browser_callback`, simply nothing happens. Perhaps I'm using it wrong. I updated the answer with the code

Comment: have you try put thant callback function as value instead of put a "name" of function?

Comment: Something like this: `file_browser_callback: function(){...`  ?

Answer (score 3):

The editor does not provide a specific event tied to image insertion.  If you look at the source code of the `image` plugin it does fire a `change` event so you can get notified when that happens.  Code to get that notification would look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#myeditor',
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('change', function (e) {
      console.log('change event fired');
      console.log(e);
      console.log('Content changed to:  ' + editor.getContent());
    });
  }
});
```

You can then see if there are images in the changed content and do what you need from there.

Comment: Tks for the answer. It probably works, but analysis each change I think is not a good idea. BUTTTT, you give me a good idea. When user click to finish and submit to server, I will parse the html content with Nokogiri, and I will get all `img` tags and get the `alt`. And then, to save the new `alt` in the database.

Answer (score 0):

NodeChange is the event that you might be looking for. This is the code that I am using. Make sure that you put in a return at the end of the block to allow the javascript to continue to execute- otherwise, you won't be able to do stuff like editing images.

```
// When an image is inserted into the editor after image upload...
editor.on('NodeChange', function (e) {
    if (e.element.tagName === "IMG") { 
        // Set an alt attribute. We will insert the value when the image was successfully uploaded and the imageId was returned from the server. We saved the alt tag that we want into the imageId hidden input field (imageId) when the server returned data. Here, we are taking that value and inserting the new alt tag.
        e.element.setAttribute("alt", $("#imageId").val());
        return; 
    }
    return;
});
```